# input value binding does not work in loop

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to condense my code by creating reusable input fields. So I declare an array of objects to loop over and create the fields. This works fine at first glance. My problem is that the variable videoSearch is always undefined. The function gets called, but not with the value I entered. Is there an aspect of the binding I did not see? Here is my code:

```
  let values = {
    song: "",
    video: null,
    tab: null
  };

  let videoSearch;
  let tabSearch;
  let videos;

  const inputs = [
    {
      label: "Song",
      value: values.song
    },
    {
      label: "Search Youtube",
      value: videoSearch,
      func: debounce(searchYoutube, 300)
    },
    {
      label: "Search Songsterr",
      value: tabSearch,
      func: debounce(searchYoutube, 300)
    }
  ];

 async function searchYoutube() {
    console.log(videoSearch);
    if (videoSearch && videoSearch.length > 3) {
      // ... do ApiCall
    }
  }

    {#each inputs as { value, label, func }}
      <div class="input-container">
        <input on:input={func} bind:value />
        <label class={value ? 'flying-label' : ''}>{label}</label>
      </div>
    {/each}
```

EDIT

I created a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/060bddff8d1c48a7a7d03cef7b5a9261?version=3.10.0) for it.

Comment: It does look like it should work, can you create an example on [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/)?

Comment: I did. Edited the original post.

Comment: If you add an extra log to output `inputs` to your `SearchYoutube` function you see what is happening: `value` is being overwritten by the value of your input field, removing your reference to `searchYoutube`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are overwriting *value* with the inputted value removing the reference to *videoSearch*. You can easily see this by adding some logging to the *videoSearch* function:

```
async function searchYoutube() {
   console.log(inputs[1]);
   ...
}
```

If you want to use this construct, I would introduce a getter/setter in the inputs array instead of referring directly to the *videoSearch* field, this will prevent your binding from being overwritten.

```
  const inputs = [
    {
      label: "Search Youtube",
      get value() { return videoSearch; },
      set value(val) { videoSearch = val; },
      func: searchYoutube
   }
];
```